# MagicalRecord saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion seems to happen more than once causing a lot of lag/ui blocking

Tags: objective-c, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I am trying to import a large number of entities at once using MagicalRecord but the saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion is printing out several times inside the console and takes a long time to complete.

This is the save block!

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Saved the database changes");
}];
```

I appreciate there is a large number of items to save but is this normal behaviour for MagicalRecord to save more than one context of the same information? If so, can I make it simply save one context, in the background?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x18df55f0) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x18df55f0): *** UNNAMED ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x18df55f0) → Save Parents? 1
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x18df55f0) → Save Synchronously? 0
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x18df55f0) Context UNNAMED is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 18677 inserted objects
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x1765c3f0) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x1765c3f0): *** DEFAULT ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x1765c3f0) → Save Parents? 1
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x1765c3f0) → Save Synchronously? 0
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x1765c3f0) Context DEFAULT is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 18677 inserted objects
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x1765de80) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x1765de80): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x1765de80) → Save Parents? 1
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x1765de80) → Save Synchronously? 0
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x1765de80) Context BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 18677 inserted objects
__70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke25(0x1765de80) → Finished saving: <NSManagedObjectContext (0x1765de80): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
```

UPDATE 1:

I have just found that using the following speeds the time up quite a bit but it still seems to save 3 times.

```
[MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Saved the database changes");
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since anything saving operation that you are doing using the designated methods are performing the task on the `mainThread`, that is why you see a UI-Blocking & lagging.

If you go back to the file [MagicalRecord+Actions.h](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/58491056010d690500864aa81c3d10de5ebe4e69/MagicalRecord/Core/MagicalRecord%2BActions.h) & verify, then you will find other methods that work on the `backgroundThread`, namely :

[`+ (void) saveWithBlock:(void(^)(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext))block;`](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/58491056010d690500864aa81c3d10de5ebe4e69/MagicalRecord/Core/MagicalRecord%2BActions.h#L16)

[`+ (void) saveWithBlock:(void(^)(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext))block completion:(MRSaveCompletionHandler)completion;`](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/58491056010d690500864aa81c3d10de5ebe4e69/MagicalRecord/Core/MagicalRecord%2BActions.h#L17)

try using this & it will avoid the `mainThread` blocking as operation will be performed in background thread.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Using this method does not save the data! NSLog says:-

    [NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x1d205090) NO CHANGES IN ** UNNAMED ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING

Comment: @WillRoberts what is the proper solution at this moment? I would like to use this method also but it looks like it does not use the correct context.